# pH calculations for boiler water

Tags: chemical-engineering, steam, chemistry, boilers

For water steam cycle in a "combined cycle power plant" containing 3 boiler drums and dosing of 5% ammonia solution in the condenser. How can I calculate the pH of the boiler water in each of the drums? (LP- 4.6 bar, IP- 36 bar, HP- 162 bar)

Comment: This is done using acid/base calculations. A search for "calculate pH of ammonia solution" should return the information that you will need, including on-line calculators and video tutorials. Otherwise, please add information to your question as to what makes your system different than what can be found by such a search.

Comment: Original water ?, No make-up water?, No phosphate addition ( to prevent caustic cracking)?, No mud drum?, No steam drum ?

Answer (score 1):

Do they provide you with the temperature of the system? In this case what they want you to do is solve first the boiler mass balance, in case there are heat/temperature specs you could make a energy balance (taking into account the Keq of the dissociation of ammonia along with the Keq of the disociation of water that does change at higher temperatures)

To solve the energy balance I would recommend you using Bird but given the nature of your problem I would recommend things closer to [this](http://faculty.poly.edu/~rlevicky/Handout6.pdf)